# Three.js: limit drag and drop with certain distance

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, drag-and-drop

How can I limit a distance of dragging and dropping an object in Three.js using DragControl? I need to limit a distance from new to initial object position and prevent a user to drag further.

Answer (score 1):

You can register new event listeners in DragControls. The code below demonstrates one way to do this. It resets the object to the starting position if the distance between the start and end vectors is greater than `maxDistance`

```
  const dragControls = new DragControls(objects, camera, renderer.domElement)
  
  // create variables to hold starting vector and selected object
  let startPos
  let selected
  // max distance between start and end vectors
  const maxDistance = 500
  
  // check vector difference on mouseup
  renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    if (selected && startPos) {
      console.log('distance', Math.abs(startPos.distanceTo(selected.position)))
      if (Math.abs(startPos.distanceTo(selected.position)) > maxDistance) {
        selected.position.copy(startPos)
      }
    }
    selected = null
});
  
  // set startPos and selected on mousedown
  renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouse = new THREE.Vector2()
    mouse.x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -((event.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1;
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
            if(intersects.length > 0) {
                selected = intersects[0].object;
                startPos = new THREE.Vector3(selected.position.x, selected.position.y, selected.position.z)
                console.log('startPos',{...startPos})
            }
});
```

DragControls is a very simple library (one class, see https://github.com/jbyte/three-dragcontrols). I would just reimplement the class in your own project and add startPos and maxDistance as properties, then you would have a nice, clean, reusable implementation without the extra event listeners and globals above.